# How do you enable background scrolling even though Angular material dialog is opened?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

Let's say, I have a table on my page with 100 items, and scrolling is enabled. I have opened an Angular [dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) but still, need to enable the table scrolling. By default, when you make `disableClose: true` or `disableClose: false` you can't scroll the background table rows. I need to enable table rows scrolling when a dialog's option is `disableClose: true`.

Also, I tried with `scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block()` which does not work as well.

Comment: Hi, Have you found an answer or a way out?

Comment: As I understand it, `scrollStrategies.block()` blocks scrolling. Have you tried using `scrollStrategies.noop()` instead? An example: 
`this.dialog.open(SomeDialogComponent, { scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.noop() });` -- You could also try to initialize your scrollVariable in the constructor, and use it similarly.